# coldfusion/jquery like dislike functionality mysql DB size optimization concern

Tags: mysql, database, coldfusion

We are only a few days away from launching our new website, hence we started putting the finishing touches on the development process. Although everything works great due to our effort to optimize every part of the application, my partner has raised a question about mysql database size and possible issue we could end up with over time. More specifically, we built like dislike functionality (cfc, jquery) which though works flawlessly will significantly increase the DB size if we manage to attract a lot of visitors.

here is our logic:
- every user can vote only once on one article (vote up or vote down) as we store IP in the DB
- say 10 000 users come to the website and vote on 10 posts, that's 100 000 inserts (via stored procedure) and 100 000 rows in our database. Count that by 10,100 or 1000, you get the picture.

votes table has 4 colums
- typeID (voteUp = 1 and voteDown = 2)
- articleID
- IP
- vCount (we use it to count SUM, how many votes each article has)

are we missing the point here? in your experience what's the best approach to handle this type of functionality?

Comment: Databases are meant to store data, and MySQL, SQL Server, etc. are able to efficiently store large amounts of data that eclipse what your site will probably ever muster. The most important part for your consideration, then, is not the *number* of records that are recorded, but how efficiently your code is written to interact with this data. With some indexes and smart queries, a very large table of this kind should not be an issue.

Comment: One more thing: it might be wise to add upvote and downvote sum columns to your article table itself. That way you don't have to query the votes table just to get the counts. You can then save the query on the votes table to those instances where you need user-specific data.

Comment: As a DBA, I'd be curious to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on the votes table. I don't understand your explanation of what vCount is doing, and it's not clear why you are using IP, and not user id, since multiple people are often behind the same IP and an individual's IP address can change even over the course of a single day, assuming IP refers to IP address.

Comment: I disagree with the suggestion about upvote and downvote sum columns.  I think it's redundant and something that can go wrong.  I also think your vCount column in the votes table serves no useful purpose.

Comment: @existdissolve we put a special emphasis on optimization, for instance we've been using indexes and stored procedures to get the fastest and most efficient interaction with mysql server.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot we use IP instead of userID because users are allowed to vote without logging in

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there's nothing wrong with your approach. Assuming that you have a not too limited data storage capacity, you should not run out of space for a long time.

You could of course use just one record per article, but this might create a bottleneck when the records needs to be locked for updating every time a user votes.

What you might consider is adding a date/time field to your votes table to store when a vote was recorded. By creating an additional table with one row per article to keep track of the over-all votes, you could query all votes that are older than let's say 12 months, update your new table accordingly, and delete the old votes from the votes table. Stuff that functionality into a scheduled task and you're done. That way you will lose the IP information (after 12 months or whatever timespan you chose) but gain back some storage.

Comment: no we do not have limited data storage capacity :) 
"You could of course use just one record per article..." I absolutely agree

Comment: "What you might consider is adding a date/time..." thank you for pointing this out, we've been considering this approach as my partner suggested it a while back.